# Failed to load user-extensions.js: Error opening input stream , when starting Selenium IDE

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-ide

I have setup a user-extensions.js file in the Selenium IDE plugin for Firefox.
*Options > Options > Selenium Core extensions (Browse)*

Now every time I open the Selenium IDE window I get a [Javascript Application] error dialog popup which says :
*Failed to load user-extensions.js: Error opening input stream (invalid filename?): file:((path to file))/user-extensions.js?1455678175105"*
[Screen shot of the error dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erdFp.png)

**(Note : other [Javascript Application] Selenium IDE startup error messages can be fixed by the solution given below)**

Firefox version is 44.0.2
Selenium IDE version is 2.9.1
*Note that the number after the question mark changes each time.*

If I open a test suite and run it then it still works (and has, therefore, successfully loaded my user-extensions.js) - but it is a pain getting this error message every time I open Selenium.

What can I do to get rid of this error dialog?

Comment: My guess would be it doesn't like the '?1455678175105' at the end of the filename. If you actually have that in your user-extensions file name I'd remove it, if you don't then I'd check you haven't accidentally put it in the selenium options, which would cause it not to find the file if it doesn't have that in the name

Comment: It must have something to do with your current browser version.

Comment: @Jsmith2800 - I think that is the problem too, however that is not part of the file name, nor is it there in the setting in Options.  Also, that number after the ? changes every time I open Selenium IDE and get the error message.

Comment: @RodelBernal - I'm using Firefox version 44.0.2  - I'll update the question to include this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolved it :

1. Open Firefox and open Selenium IDE
2. Options > Options > set Selenium Core extensions to blank, and click OK
3. Quit Selenium IDE and quit Firefox (yes, must also quit Firefox)
4. Open Firefox and open Selenium IDE
5. Options > Options > set Selenium Core extensions back to the original user-extensions.js file (browse to it), and click OK

Thereafter it is happy, no more error messages on startup. :)